# imagecreatefromstring using image with data:image/png;base64,

Tags: php, gd

I've an image stored as string that starts with:

```
data:image/png;base64,
```

I need to convert it to a normal image for use it with GD.

I tried `imagecreatefromstring()` but it seems to accept only images without the `data:image/etc` pefix.

How can I do?

Comment: use substr() to extract the base64 data, base64_decode() it, then pass the stripped/decoded data to createfromstring()

Comment: Do I need to remove *data:image/png* also?

Comment: yes. everything EXCEPT the base64 data itself has to go.

Comment: *$image = explode('base64,',$data); $src = base64_decode($image[1]);* It's this ok for strip those things? I need to work with unknow image type.

Comment: DON'T explode like that. it's unlikely, but the base64 data may just naturally by chance contain the word 'base64' and totally trash your image.

Comment: So how can I strip those informations if I don't know if the image will be a *jpeg, png, tiff, gif* etc? Regex on the first occurence?

Comment: data uri has a pretty standard format. `data:type;base64,xxx`. just look for that first comma.

Comment: Are commas allowed in the base64 image? (the content after *base64,*),  If not, explode *base64,* (with the comma) should be fine...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$exploded = explode(',', $data, 2); // limit to 2 parts, i.e: find the first comma
$encoded = $exploded[1]; // pick up the 2nd part
$decoded = base64_decode($encoded);
$img_handler = imagecreatefromstring($decoded);
```