# Displaying jpeg using imagejpeg

Tags: php, image

I am trying to understand methods of displaying an image in a browser. This works:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($photoData) .'" />';
```

But this does not:

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring($photoData);       
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image);
```

It displays the data rather than the image. Can anyone explain what I am missing?

Comment: with the second option, are you displaying only the image or text too?

Comment: There is a typo `$photoData'`

Comment: what's the value of $photoData? an Image path or base64

Comment: It is only displaying the text (photo data)

Comment: photodata is base64. It is retrieved from my database.

Comment: What is the value of $photoData?

Comment: Add `$photoData = base64_decode($photoData);` before the imagecreate line

Comment: @LuckyChingi still no joy

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
<?php 

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

$exploded = explode(',', $photoData, 2); // limit to 2 parts, i.e: find the first comma
$encoded = $exploded[1]; // pick up the 2nd part
$decoded = base64_decode($encoded);

$im = imagecreatefromstring($decoded);       

$width = "500px";
$height = "400px";
$im2 = imagecrop($im, ['x' => 0, 'y' => 0, 'width' => $width, 'height' => $height]);

imagejpeg($im2);
// Free up memory
imagedestroy($im2);

?>
```

Image crop example **[PHPImagecrop](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecrop.php)**

**Make sure:**

That your page only prints the image because if it's contain any string or other errors it won't show the image.

I used this reference to solve your issue,
[imagecreatefromstring using image with data:image/png;base64,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18284313/3452102)

Comment: I tried this one but still no joy. Is it because there is other text on the page? This is quite a limiter - no?

Comment: do you print echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($photoData) .'" />';   in the script?

Comment: ? it is php and this method does display the image. But I need to do some manipulation (cropping for example) and so looking at the imagejpeg() method.

Comment: @RGriffiths you can crop the image, try my script. if it works mark it as the answer.

Comment: As I said I have tried this method and it does not work with my data. The cropping will not be a problem - the issue is getting the original image to a format that I can use the imagecrop method on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165274/discussion-between-praneeth-nidarshan-and-rgriffiths).